# Microsoft Graph API roles claim not in token but Application permissions added

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm attempting to connect to the Microsoft Graph API to use an excel function, as a server to server connection/flow.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-use-functions

In Azure AD I've built the registered application: [image: azure registered app]

I've created the secret...and also added the API Permissions. [image: app_permissions]

In Postman, I'm able to get the token fine.....but I notice that roles are not included in the token.  Here's the request:
[image: token request]

And then when I make a request to the excel function of RATE I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-08-17T14:31:04",
            "request-id": "b0d65e3c-4acd-4a8a-82c4-1c4c5f2216ac",
            "client-request-id": "b0d65e3c-4acd-4a8a-82c4-1c4c5f2216ac"
        }
    }
}
```

Every post I still on here mentions API permissions and granting consent as Admin....which I have completed but I'm still getting the error.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is any claims mapping policy linked to the application service principal.

1. Navigate to Azure Active Directory > Enterprise Applications > Search with the Client ID you used in your token request > copy the object ID of the app. Keep in mind that this object id is different than the object ID of the application object present under App Registration.
2. Run `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id object_id_copied_in_step_1 | fl` to check if there is any claims mapping policy linked.
3. If there is a cliams mapping policy linked to it, run `Remove-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy` to remove the policy.

Decode your bearer token at https://jwt.ms to confirm if the Roles claim is populated or not. SCP claim will not be populated in this case, as it only populates when the token is acquired under user context.